# How to Change Azure Active Directory Subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, hana

I activated the free trail Azure Subscription. Afterwards I deleted the Azure subscription. After a few months I activated a Visual Studio Dev Essentials Subscription.

I try to use in active directory I saw start the free trail to use this feature. I have another subscription. How can I remove and use this feature.

[image]

And when i try to create the enterprise applications I was getting this error

[image]

[image]

How can I change subscription and activate add enterprise application in active directory. Anyone who knows reply to me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please make your question more clearly, it is unclear if this is one or two problems. If there are 2 problems, try to seperate them.

Comment: Does your free trail Azure Subscription still active?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT it's Show Disable

Comment: @umasankar  if we want to integration SAP HANA Cloud Platform with Azure Active Directory, we need a valid Azure subscription, so we can't use that free trail Azure subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP Hana Cloud Identity Platform Require the Enterprise Premium Active Directory. I was Enable free Trial of Enterprise Premium Active Directory in inside my azure Account.

It's Not azure Subscription. It's feature of Azure Active Directory of Premium License.the SAP Hana Hana and Some other Enterprise Application Requires Premium Azure Active Directory. that's only Failed to Create Application.

[image]

we enable Premium trial then it's Create Successfully. In Enterprise Applications
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your free trial Azure Subscription was **disabled**, if we want to integration Azure Active Directory with SAP HANA cloud platform, we should have `a valid subscription`. So we **can't** use free trial Azure subscription to integrate SAP HANA Cloud platform.

More information about integration Azure AD with SAP HANA Cloud platform, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-sap-hana-cloud-platform-tutorial).

If you want to migrate Azure AD from one subscription to another, maybe we can refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/12275436-migrate-azure-ad-from-one-subscription-to-another).

> This trust relationship that a subscription has with a directory is
>   unlike the relationship that a subscription has with all other
>   resources in Azure (websites, databases, and so on), which are more
>   like child resources of a subscription. If a subscription expires,
>   then access to those other resources associated with the subscription
>   also stops. But the directory remains in Azure, and you can associate
>   another subscription with that directory and continue to manage the
>   directory users.

Comment: What can I do for you? Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance :)